# Doctrine entity not updated when passed as argument

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

I've an instance of a Doctrine entity which is passed as argument to a method of a Symfony service.

I do all the data manipulation outside the method but for some reason this changes are not reflected in the method.

For example:

```
// I've a payment entity, the current status is "created"
// ...data manipulation...
$payment->setStatus('completed');
$this->em->flush($payment);
...
$this->myService->doStuff($payment);

// In the doStuff method...
public function doStuff(Payment $payment) {
    // The status still "created", not "completed"...
    // I don't do any find/getRepository/refresh here, so the entity should not be hydrated again
    $status = $payment->getStatus(); 
}
```

Why this happens? I do this in a Symfony/API Platform DataPersister.

An important detail: in the PHP code, if I use the logger for printing the value `$status`, it seems not updated but later when I look at the database record, it is.

This happens only in production, I can't reproduce this on my PC.

The difference is that in production I use a k8s cluster for the app and MySQL cluster for database.

I thought of a database replicas issues but, since **I'm not doing any query in the method**, it cannot be (it's a really a simple method, just checks the payment status).

Comment: first guess would be, that setStatus doesn't actually change the status or it would show up in the database, where you should check manually for a debug-session. then, there's always the option of the code not being executed at all, or having an effect later than expected, due to caching. please make sure, that after setStatus the status is actually different, and then determine the line of code, where the status is reset. from the code you show us, no error is apparent, but clearly something is wrong. But debugging is your task ;o)

Comment: @Jakumi, I forgot an important point: the updated value shows up in the db! In the PHP code, if I use the logger for printing the value, it seems not updated but when I look at the db records, it is!

Answer (score 0):

Usually API-Platform does the persisting and flushing for you at the end of the request.

It may be the case that your other service refreshes the entity from the database, or flushing the entity manager without persisting the entity causes a refresh of the entity, setting back your in-memory changes, thus it may make sense to persist it before that (analyze Doctrine logs if that is the case).

So in that case, you simply forgot to persist the entity before flushing.

```
$em->persist($entity):
$em->flush();
```

Also note that passing an entity to the flush method is deprecated (if not already removed).